# Using LINQ how would I check if a XML row contains a field and if it does check a different field on the same row for a value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a scenario where an application is spitting out some XML to me and I don't have any control of what it's structure is I have posted it below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DATASET xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
    <ROW> 
        <OccNumber >test</OccNumber>
        <OccId >Test2</OccId>
        <OccTime >2017/01/26 09:38</OccTime>
        <OccSummary >Test worked</OccSummary>
        <DATASET>
            <ROW>
                <PID>123456</PID>
                <CID >12345678</CID>
            </ROW>
            <ROW>
                <PID>569867</PID>
                <CID>37576334</CID>
            </ROW>
        <DATASET>
            <ROW>
                <ReportId >4345454</ReportId>
                <ReportTime >2018/02/15 12:55</ReportTime>
                <NumberType4 />
                <accepted >Yes</accepted>
                <cond1>No </Cond1>
            </ROW>
        </DATASET>
    </ROW>
</DATASET>
```

So what I need to do is basically count any time I find a  tag and with in the same row the  tag has a value of "Yes". I would like to do this with LINQ if possible.

EDIT:
To be a bit more clear.  I am assuming that because the Dataset and Row tag's repeat and don't have a unique name I can't identify a specific one to check for my count.  What I do know is that the ACCEPTED and COND1 tags are unique to the data-set and row I am interested in counting.  I also need to check the values in both fields as it's a combination of what I find that tells me if I should count the row or not.

Comment: Why do you care if it’s on the same row?

Comment: @zzxyz Because that Row field could be repeated and it's the combination of the two fields within the row that makes it count. if I have COND1 = Yes but no Accepted I don't want to count it. same as I don't want to count if ACCEPTED is found and COND1 = No

Comment: -Sorry I only scanned the data and thought literal text row. Although the clarification is probably still useful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML isn't valid (missing closing tag on one of the DATASET elements, different case in the cond1 element).  Below is some corrected XML with additional nodes that can be used for testing and some code beneath it showing how you can select the nodes you're interested in.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DATASET xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
    <ROW> 
        <OccNumber >test</OccNumber>
        <OccId >Test2</OccId>
        <OccTime >2017/01/26 09:38</OccTime>
        <OccSummary >Test worked</OccSummary>
       <DATASET>
            <ROW>
                <ReportId >4345454</ReportId>
                <ReportTime >2018/02/15 12:55</ReportTime>
                <NumberType4 />                
                <cond1>No</cond1>
            </ROW>
        </DATASET>      
        <DATASET>
            <ROW>
                <ReportId >4345454</ReportId>
                <ReportTime >2018/02/15 12:55</ReportTime>
                <NumberType4 />
                <accepted>Yes</accepted>
                <cond1>No</cond1>
            </ROW>
        </DATASET>              
        <DATASET>
            <ROW>
                <PID>123456</PID>
                <CID >12345678</CID>
            </ROW>
            <ROW>
                <PID>569867</PID>
                <CID>37576334</CID>
            </ROW>
        </DATASET>
        <DATASET>
            <ROW>
                <ReportId >4345454</ReportId>
                <ReportTime >2018/02/15 12:55</ReportTime>
                <NumberType4 />
                <accepted>Yes</accepted>
                <cond1>No</cond1>
            </ROW>
        </DATASET>
    </ROW>
</DATASET>
```

Code:

```
var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml("YOUR XML STRING HERE");
var nodes = xdoc.SelectNodes("//DATASET/ROW[accepted='Yes' and cond1='No']");
```

Comment: Thanks @CaseyR , I will try it out, by chance is there a way to do this with XDocument? it's what the rest of the program is using and I noticed it does not have a SelectNodes option.

Comment: Just tried this and it worked:

`var xdoc = XDocument.Parse("YOUR XML STRING HERE");
    var nodes = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//DATASET/ROW[accepted='Yes' and cond1='No']");`